# jQuery .closest() returns multiple results within a custom jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, closest

While hacking my free-time project I stumbled upon a puzzling jQuery behaviour.

I have a custom validation plugin written and working. In the plugin I wanted to implement some functionality using .closest() method. Strangely enough this method returns multiple elements.

Here is a sample code:

```
this.closest(".control-group")
$(this).closest(".control-group");
```

Both above code lines select all four elements with class "control-group". This code put inside my plugin works:

```
var element_ID = this.attr("id");
$("#" + element_ID).closest(".control-group")
```

Above selects the correct and only one element with "control-group" class.

I can't use this "hack" as not all elements that I want to validate have "id" property set, so it won't work in all cases.

Using jQuery 1.7.2 (seems to be latest stable). Any ideas why it's like that?

Comment: try console.log(this.length)and see if this points to more than one element

Answer (score 6):

`this` is a jQuery object that contains at least 4 DOM elements, and calling `.closest` on it will retrieve the closest `.control-group` elements for all of those.

`this.attr("id")` will retrieve the id of the first dom element in the jQuery object, so you could have just done `$(this[0]).closest...`

Comment: In the context above **this** is a element being validated. According to the .closest() docs, it travels up in the DOM tree so it should search for the elements above **this** element and return element with "control-group" class which is "closest" to **this**. But it returns all elements from DOM tree.

Comment: @koniczynek `this` is a jQuery object, otherwise you wouldn't be able to call `this.closest()` like that.

Comment: I know it's already a jQuery object, the main question is why .closest() returns four elements when called **this.closest()** and only one when called like this **$("#" + this.attr("id")).closest()** (this is the correct behaviour).

Comment: I already explained, `this.attr("id")` returns the id of the **first** element encapsulated by the jQuery object. So you now have a jQuery object with only one element, so calling `.closest` on that jQuery object will retrieve only 1 element at maximum. Calling `.closest` on a jQuery object and getting 4 elements as a result means that the jQuery object was holding at least 4 elements.

Comment: .closest() by definition should return 0 or 1 element (this says the docs). Inside my custom plugin **this** should contain only one element, is this correct?

Comment: @koniczynek no it returns 0 or 1 elements, **per** element held in the jQuery object. See http://jsfiddle.net/BQLs6/ Hence, if you get 4 elements from calling `something.closest`, that `something` jQuery object must have held at least 4 elements.

Comment: my mistake here, you were absolutely right! No it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

you may not have id's for all the elements but you do have `this`

instead of

```
var element_ID = this.attr("id");
$("#" + element_ID).closest(".control-group")
```

try

```
$(this).closest(".control-group")
```

**Update**

The jQuery site says:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
> .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors
> in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching
> elements. The .parents() and .closest() methods are similar in that
> they both traverse up the DOM tree. The differences between the two,
> though subtle, are significant:
>
> .**closest()** : The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element
>
> .**parents()** : The returned jQuery object contains zero, one, or
> multiple elements

here is the link: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

So your original question is maybe not answered

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I already tried that and it does not work. I will add this to the question.

Comment: Inside a jQuery plugin, `this` already is a jQuery object. No need to pass it to jQuery again. `$(this)` is the same as `$($('some selector'))`.

Comment: The docs can seem contradictory as the descritipion says that *constructs a new jQuery object from the matching **elements***. It can indeed return a jQuery object holding multiple elements if the target jQuery object was holding multiple elements. http://jsfiddle.net/BQLs6/